# Envio do conteúdo de uma div por email com php mailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php require_once ("cabecalho.php");?>
<div id="menor">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <form action="envia-texto.php" method="post">
            <div id="texto" name="texto">
                <h5 class="center-align black-text"><?php ini_set('display_errors', 1);
                    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
                    error_reporting(E_ALL);
                    if(isset($_POST['titulo'])){

                        echo $_POST['titulo'] . ' ';
                    }?>                     
                </h5><br>
                <h6 class="black-text">
                    <?php ini_set('display_errors', 1);
                    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
                    error_reporting(E_ALL);

                    if(isset($_POST['introducao'])) {

                        echo $_POST['introducao'] . ' ';
                    }?>
                </h6>
                <h6 class="black-text">
                    <?php ini_set('display_errors', 1);
                    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
                    error_reporting(E_ALL);

                    if(isset($_POST['argumento1'])) {

                        echo $_POST['argumento1'] . ' ';
                    }?>
                </h6>
                <h6 class="black-text">
                    <?php ini_set('display_errors', 1);
                    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
                    error_reporting(E_ALL);

                    if(isset($_POST['argumento2'])) {

                        echo $_POST['argumento2'] . ' ';
                    }?>
                </h6>
                <h6 class="black-text">
                    <?php ini_set('display_errors', 1);
                    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
                    error_reporting(E_ALL);

                    if(isset($_POST['argumento3'])) {

                        echo $_POST['argumento3'] . ' ';
                    }?>
                </h6>
                <h6 class="black-text">
                    <?php ini_set('display_errors', 1);
                    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
                    error_reporting(E_ALL);

                    if(isset($_POST['conclusao'])) {

                        echo $_POST['conclusao'] . ' ';
                    }?>
                </h6>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
                <input class="validate" id="nome" type="text" name="nome">
                <label for="nome" class="black-text">Nome Completo</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
                <input class="validate" id="email1" type="email" name="email1">
                <label for="email1" class="black-text">Seu Email</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
                <input type="password" name="senha" id="senha">
                <label for="senha" class="black-text">Sua Senha</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
                <input class="validate" id="email2" type="email" name="email2">
                <label for="email2" class="black-text">Email Alvo</label>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12 center">
                <br>
                <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light red" value="Enviar2" type="submit">
                    <i class="material-icons right">send</i>enviar
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<?php include 'rodape.php';?>
```

Quando clica no botão enviar, é carregado o código `enviar-texto.php`, que é esse

```
<?php
session_start();
$texto = $_POST["texto"];
$email2 = $_POST["email2"];
$email1 = $_POST["email1"];
$senha = $_POST["senha"];
$nome = $_POST["nome"];

require_once("PHPMailerAutoload.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = $email1;
$mail->Password = $senha;

$mail->setFrom($email1, $nome);
$mail->addAddress($email2);
$mail->Subject = "Redação de um usuário VestCollege";
$mail->msgHTML("<html>{$texto}</html>");
$mail->AltBody = $texto;
if($mail->send()) {
  header("Location: home.php");
} else {
  $_SESSION["danger"] = "Erro ao enviar mensagem " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  header("Location: phptexto.php");
}
die();
```

Funciona assim: é preenchido os campos titulo, introducao, argumento 1, etc. Aí esses pedaços são juntados e carregados dentro da div "texto", porém quando vou enviar por email a div vai vazia pra lá e não sei qual o problema.

Se for relevante dizer estou usando framework materialize css. me ajudem por favor, pois nao sei o que fazer.

Comment: No seu contexto não pode enviar dados contidos em uma div

Comment: e tem alguma ideia de como eu posso fazer pra isso dar certo?

Comment: joga o conteúdo da div dentro de <textarea id="textoA" name="textoA" style="display:none"> CONTEUDO AQUI</textarea> e lá na enviar $texto = $_POST["textoA"];

Comment: primeiro esses display: none ta fazendo o textarea não aparecer na tela. segundo eu tirei esses display aí ao inves de aparecer o texto digitado ta aparecendo as tags html que tem dentro da div

Comment: Jovem, o display:none no textarea é para não aparecer mesmo na tela já que essas informações já constam na div. É somente para você poder enviar esse conteúdo dentro dessa div para enviar-texto.php.

Comment: Deu certo obrigado

Comment: publiquei como resposta,  leia https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Comment: obrigado não sabia desse negócio da resposta. marquei ali agora

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joga o conteúdo da div dentro de um textarea    `display:none` (para não aparecer mesmo na tela)

`<textarea id="textoA" name="textoA" style="display:none"> CONTEUDO AQUI</textarea>`

e na pagina enviar-texto.php  recupera assim

```
$texto = $_POST["textoA"];
```

Conteúdo da div

```
<textarea id="textoA" name="textoA" style="display:none">            
    <h5 class="center-align black-text">
    <?php
        echo $_POST['titulo'] . ' ';
    ?>                     
    </h5><br>
    ....................
    ....................
    ....................
</textarea>
```